# Hook into login (MVC4)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Is there any way to hook into (I want to perform a check for certain conditions directly after login) the login process in ASP.NET MVC4. I am using the default MemberShip classes provided by Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create your on AuthorizeAttribute and implement your login on OnAuthorization method.

Here's a sample:

```
  public class AuthenticateAndAuthorizeAcsMvcAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var principal = filterContext.HttpContext.User;
        if (principal == null || !principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult()
            {
                ViewName = "AcsLogin",
                ViewData = filterContext.Controller.ViewData,
                TempData = filterContext.Controller.TempData
            };
            return;

        }
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }

}
```

Comment: Following your code I get the following Exception: "The given filter instance must implement one or more of the following filter interfaces: IAuthorizationFilter, IActionFilter, IResultFilter, IExceptionFilter." When using System.Web.Http and when using System.Web.Mvc it says there is no suitable method to override.

Comment: @Choraimy sorry, I just found the code on the codeproject and could not test it. I was just showing you that you should override the OnAuthorization method. I've fixed the sample above. Cheers.